# Flask application deployment with mod_wsgi import error of own package

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

This might be a repetitive question, but still I couldn't address my current situation. I am trying to deploy a flask application on localhost port 8080 but am running to import errors. Here is the detail:

```
[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=5400): Target WSGI script '/home/btruhand/public_html/wsgi/TwitterIntersection.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module. [Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=5400): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/btruhand/public_html/wsgi/TwitterIntersection.wsgi'. 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last): 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/btruhand/public_html/wsgi/TwitterIntersection.wsgi", line 5, in <module> 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from twitterintersect import app as application [Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/btruhand/public_html/apps/TwitterIntersection/twitterintersect/__init__.py", line 8, in <module> 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from twitterintersect import views 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/btruhand/public_html/apps/TwitterIntersection/twitterintersect/views.py", line 1, in <module> 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from twitterintersect import app, db, hackedtwitter, tasks [Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/btruhand/public_html/apps/TwitterIntersection/twitterintersect/tasks.py", line 1, in <module> 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from twitterintersect import app, db_models, hackedtwitter, appInfo 

[Sun Feb 09 14:32:29 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: cannot import name hackedtwitter
```

twitterintersect is a package and it's layout is as follow:

```
TwitterIntersection/
---twitterintersect/
-----__init__.py
-----views.py
-----tasks.py
-----hackedtwitter.py
-----some other files
```

Where TwitterIntersection is in ~/public_html/apps/

To give more info here is my TwitterIntersection.wsgi file in ~/public_html/wsgi:

```
activate_this='/home/btruhand/public_html/apps/TwitterIntersection/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this,dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/btruhand/public_html/apps/TwitterIntersection/')
from twitterintersect import app as application
```

And here is my site configuration file which is activated and located in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    # ---- Configure VirtualHost Defaults ----

ServerAdmin root@localhost 

    DocumentRoot /home/btruhand/public_html/http

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/btruhand/public_html/http/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    # ---- Configure WSGI Listener(s) ----

    WSGIDaemonProcess TwitterIntersection user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /twitterintersection /home/btruhand/public_html/wsgi/TwitterIntersection.wsgi 

    <Directory /home/btruhand/public_html/http/twitterintersection>
            WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # ---- Configure Logging ----

ErrorLog /home/btruhand/public_html/logs/error_twitter_intersection.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /home/btruhand/public_html/logs/access_twitter_intersection.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Really confused as to what is going on. Executing TwitterIntersection.wsgi using the python command manually does not pose a problem.

EDIT:
Oh I forgot to mention that both app and db are defined in __init__.py. Putting it out in case it helps

EDIT2:
Alright I managed to make things going. As pointed out by Graham Dumpleton, for anyone who have the same problem as me, make sure that the files in your package can be accessed by the user under the WSGIDaemonProcess configuration in your configuration file.

Comment: Presumably you quoted your configuration wrongly. The argument to WSGIProcessGroup doesn't match the name of the only WSGIDaemonProcess defined and so mod_wsgi should complain about that. As to your issue, make sire that the user www-data can actually read your files.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't notice that the process group name was not correct. Would it be sufficient to do chmod -R o+rx twitterintersect in order for the www-data user to be able to read my files in the?

Comment: Alright I've got it running but it appears now I'm getting 404 when trying to access http://localhost:8080/twitterintersection/ however a view function is registered for this URL

Comment: Show the way you are marking the view function to handle the root URL for the site. You should not have the /twitterintersection URL prefix as part of route strings in your code as the WSGI server deals with that part.